# How to use ViewAccessScope in deltaspike?

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi, codi

I used Apache CODI ViewAccessScope in my jsf application. But when i migrate Apache CODI to DeltaSpike (version 0.4), i did't find VViewAccessScope. Can anyone advise me, how to use ViewAccessScope with DeltaSpike

Comment: Replacing CODI is not recommended yet.

Comment: Replacing code 6 years later IS recommended

Answer (score 1):

I userd org.apache.deltaspike.core.api.scope.ViewAccessScoped and worked like a charm.

All i had to do was put the folloging dependencies in my pom.xml:

```html
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.deltaspike.core</groupId>
   <artifactId>deltaspike-core-api</artifactId>
   <version>1.5.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.deltaspike.core</groupId>
   <artifactId>deltaspike-core-impl</artifactId>
   <version>1.5.1</version>
   <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.deltaspike.modules</groupId>
   <artifactId>deltaspike-jsf-module-api</artifactId>
   <version>1.5.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.deltaspike.modules</groupId>
   <artifactId>deltaspike-jsf-module-impl</artifactId>
   <version>1.5.1</version>
   <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

They're implementing it now, wait till 0.5.

Comment: Currently it is in deltaspike (has been for a long time)

Answer (score 0):

Currently it isn't in DeltaSpike. I don't see that they started with it. Anyway, today I learned about http://os890.blogspot.com/2013/07/add-on-codi-scopes-for-deltaspike.html That works perfectly fine in a first test. It looks like it's the original implementation based on DeltaSpike modules instead of CODI-Core.

Comment: Currently it is in deltaspike (has been for a long time)